# Passing variable from response to request in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

In need to pass a data from a response to the subsequent request. Something goes wrong and the default variable value appears in the request.

First request returns the JSON in response body which looks like this:

`{"issued_at":"2016-01-14T12:41:01.000Z","expires":"2016-01-14T12:46:01.000Z","id":"j6M ... MTA=="}`
[image]

I extract the value of the id attribute using the Regular Expression Extractor:

[image]

Then I pass the `token` variable to the subsequent request parameter:

[image]

But the request is created with the default value of the variable:
[image]

Answer (score 10):

There is a [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) designed to deal with JSON content type, I believe it would be easier to use it.

The relevant JSON Path query will be as simple as `$..id`

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for comprehensive information on plugin installation and usage and [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) for JSONPath language reference and examples.

In regards to your Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

- remove `1` from Match No.
- Provide `$1$` as Template

Comment: What a great plugin! Far way better than use BSF Postprocessor, load java json libraries, etc ... :)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [Regular Expression Extractor documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), the field Template is required. I suggest you to use value $1$ and try again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was resolved by setting the "Field to check" radio button to "Body" at the "Regular Expression Extractor" dialog and by setting the Template field value to $1$.
Thanks to [alphamikevictor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4382794/alphamikevictor) and [Dmitri T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897748/dmitri-t) for help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `${token_g1}` to get the value of the first group of the regex match (the value you're looking for).